# Why doesn't RegExp Prototype work properly?

Tags: javascript

RegExp.prototype only work for:

```
var a = /abc/g
a.tester()

var b = /xyz/
b.tester()
```

Doesn't work with:

1. `/abc/g.tester()`
2. `/abc/.tester()`

Is there a way I can fix this so all three can work?

**Headsup**
It needs to be a `RegExp.prototype`
Question: How does the native `.test()` do it?

## What Works

```js
RegExp.prototype.tester = function(s, v) {
  console.log("I'm working")
  console.log(this)
}

a = /abc/g
b = /xyz/
a.tester()
b.tester()
```

## Problems

```js
RegExp.prototype.tester = function(s, v) {
  console.log("I'm working")
  console.log(this)
}

/abc/g.tester() //This is a problem
/abc/.tester() //This is a problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a syntax error, not a problem with the prototypical inheritance (and calling `.test` instead of `.tester` wouldn't make a difference). Use semicolons!

```
RegExp.prototype.tester = function (s,v) {
    console.log("I'm working")
    console.log(this)
}; /*
 ^ */

/abc/g.tester(); // now it's not a problem
/abc/.tester();  // any more
```

What was happening here is that the parser interpreted your code as one large statement:

```
… = function(){…} / abc / g.tester() / abc / .tester();
```

Indeed the property access `.` after the division operator `/` is an unexpected token.

If you want to omit semicolons and [let them be automatically inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) where ever <s>possible</s> needed, you will [need to put one at the *begin*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201206065632/http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) of every line that starts with `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, `-` or `` ` ``.

Comment: A good example of why getting into the habit of using semi colons is a good idea.