# Array.prototype.forEach native implementation issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement native forEach method. Here's my code:

```
Array.prototype.myEach = function(cb) {
     for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
         cb(this[i], i)
     }
}
```

If I declare `let a = []` (something) and then run `[].myEach` then it works.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]; // or even []

[1,2,3,4,5].myEach(function(val, i){
    console.log(val); //works
});
```

But if I don't declare the array on the top, it's not even recognizing the prototype.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].myEach(function(val, i){ //fails
    console.log(val);
});
```

**Problem:**

**If I remove let a = [1,2,3,4,5], doing [1,2,3,4].forEach fails.**

I'm not able to understand why.

Comment: I'm not overwriting it. I'm creating my own ForEach (myEach) to learn native methods.

Comment: You need a semicolon after your assignment statement to `Array.prototype.myEach`. Otherwise it parses the brackets as accessing a property of the function you're assigning.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46965567/1048572

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include a semi-colon after the myEach function:

```
Array.prototype.myEach = function(cb) {
     for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
         cb(this[i], i)
     }
};

[1,2,3,4,5].myEach(function(val, i){ 
    console.log(val);
});
```

Without the semi-colon, this parses like this:

```
Array.prototype.myEach = function(cb) {
     for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
         cb(this[i], i)
     }
}[1,2,3,4,5].myEach( ....etc
```

and `[1,2,3,4,5]` attempts to obtain property `5` from the function (object) - as if you had written `function(){}[5]`. There is no property `5` and so this is undefined and attempting to call myEach on undefined gives an error.

The original worked because the intermediate let statement achieved the separation (thanks to the semi-colon but irrelevant of the actual `let a =` statement).

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: good work debugging @andrew

Comment: My original answer described it as a syntax error but the actual error is that it tries to call myEach on an undefined value. I updated the explanation.